# Remove Shipping Address Info in PayPal

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'd like to hide or remove the shipping details or info in PayPal because we provide only services, thus we don't require the Shipping details to show in PayPal checkout page. I am using `PayPal RestAPISDK`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the RESTful APIs do not yet have support for the NOSHIPPING variable that is used in the Classic APIs. Address handling is something that is being discussed for future releases.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem and sorted it out to some extent.

You just add the following parameter
redirectUrl += "&shipping=0";

and shipping address will not get displayed.